# ZKoss Detect Browser (Older IE) on zul Files

Tags: javascript, html, css, zk, zul

I have a bootstrap theme that I want to implement on zul code.

There is a HTML code that detect older IE version and render page to download newer IE.

How can I implement this code on ZK (zul) files? A direct copy-paste code from HTML to zul does not work:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div class="ie-warning">
<h1 class="c-white">Warning!!</h1>
<p>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer</p>       
</div>
... more html code using <span>, <h2> and other native html tags
...
...   
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression language and [ZK's implizit objects](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Implicit_Objects/zk)

```
<div id='ie' if='${not empty zk.ie and zk.ie lt 9}'>
    visible for ie &lt; 9
</div>
<div id='nonie' if='${empty zk.ie or zk.ie ge 9}' >
    visible for non ie and ie &ge;9
</div>
```

[Here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/pena2b/2-ZK-Question-33850734) you can find a ZKFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZK 8, you can use the zhtml file type which is the same as the HTML content. For more details, you can have a look at this [article](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/March/ZK8_Series:_Build_Your_Own_Responsive_Website_in_10_Seconds).